# capture last XXX characters

Tags: bash, sed

I done a script (avconv) that re-encode my mp3 files, I'd like add a check (if I try to re-encode to same bitrate I chosen, script has to skip that file)

So, with avconv I can do:

```
avconv -i mp3test.mp3 2>&1 |grep Audio|tail -c 09
```

output is:

```
[before 8 there's a space] 80 kb/s
```

or might be:

```
128 kb/s
```

what's the best way to compare output to variable of script? (if / then / elif?)

```
if [ $VAR1 = " 80 kb/s" ] ; then
```

I guess use sed or awk to capture last number values of?

Comment: If you have access to the utility `mp3info` (available on Ubuntu/Debian) or something equivalent it might be better than parsing the output of `avconv`. For example, with `mp3info` you could obtain the bitrate easily in a variable `var` with just: `var=$(mp3info -p '%r' mp3test.mp3)`. With such utilities you can very easily have lots of informations about the files without clunky parsing.

Comment: Also, people generally discourage using `avconv`. use _original_ * `ffmpeg` instead. (* from www.ffmpeg.org). AFAIK, `avconv` has been forked out of `ffmpeg` mainstream at an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below command to extract the last string 128 or 80 kb/s.

```
sed 's/.*\ \(.*\) kb\/s/\1\ kb\/s/g'
```

OR

```
sed 's/.*\ \(.*\)\ \(.*\)/\1\ \2/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "[before 8 there's a space] 80 kb/s" | sed 's/.*\ \(.*\) kb\/s/\1\ kb\/s/g'
80 kb/s
$ echo "[before 8 there's a space] 80 kb/s" | sed 's/.*\ \(.*\)\ \(.*\)/\1\ \2/g'
80 kb/s
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think it's better try to capture like numeric value, so I can compare with a number, ie: if VAR1 > 75 and < 85 then convert to 80 Kb/s. Sometimes I find some mp3 files with strange bitrate like 78 or 82. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering you have assigned the output to a variable, say `var`, if you simply want to detect if a given information is present in your variable, you could either use a match:

```
$ if [[ ${var} =~ "80 kb/s" ]]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

Or even `grep`:

```
$ if [[ $(grep -c "80 kb/s" <<< ${var}) -ge 1 ]]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

Still, if you need to extract the matched pattern, for the first case, you may dump the match from the comparison, as in:

```
$ [[ ${var} =~ "80 kb/s" ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
80 kb/s
```

Or, for `grep`:

```
$ grep -o "80 kb/s" <<< ${var}
80 kb/s
```

**Edit**:
In case you have arbitrary values, that are always followed by "kb/s", and you want to perform operations with such values, you may do:

```
$ var="[before 8 there's a space] 80 kb/s"
$ [[ ${var} =~ ([0-9]*)" kb/s" ]] && value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ [[ $value -ge 75 && $value -le 85 ]] && echo "$value kb/s in range 75-85 kb/s"
80 kb/s in range 75-85 kb/s
```